# Multiple INNER JOIN returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on joining 3 tables.

```
table1.
grp_id | email_id
   1   |  3 
   1   |  58

table2.
sam_msg_id | sam_subject
   3       |  Funnel

table3.
id | subject
58 | testing check


Desired Output:

id |grp_id|email_id|sam_subject|subject      |
184|1     |3       |funnel     |             |
185|1     |58      |           |testing check|
```

the query I tried:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.sam_subject, table3.* 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.sam_msg_id = table1.email_id 
INNER JOIN table3 
    ON table3.id = table1.email_id 
WHERE table1.grp_id = '1'
```

What I'm trying to do here is to get the list of subject and its id from table2 and table3 where the id is found at table1 under email_id.

When I tried doing it with one inner join only by checking only the data from table2 it was working.

I am not familiar in using inner joins thus I can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: Is there actually a matching related row in table3? If not, this ought to be a `LEFT JOIN` between table1 and table3

Comment: You probably want to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: you may want to use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: there is a matching row between table1 and 2 and table1 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.sam_subject, table3.* 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
    ON table2.sam_msg_id = table1.email_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 
    ON table3.id = table1.email_id 
WHERE table1.grp_id = '1'
```

Based on you edit, the following should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT t1.grp_id, 
  t1.email_id, 
  coalesce(t2.sam_subject, '') sam_subject, 
  coalesce(t3.subject, '') subject
FROM t1
left JOIN t2 
    ON t2.sam_msg_id = t1.email_id 
left JOIN t3 
    ON t1.email_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.grp_id = '1'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab920/6)

Comment: thank you for this mate. could you do a bit of summary as how that worked. thanks. :)

Comment: The best explanation will come from the [Visual Explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). You were joining with an `INNER` which required a matching row in all 3 tables. You have separate rows that match so you need a `LEFT JOIN` to return your results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about what you are asking.  If you can provide an example of your current data and your desired output we can probably nail down a solution.

As it is, I suspect you need to read up on `LEFT JOIN`, which will return `NULL` if there is no matching record in your child table.  `INNER JOIN` will not return a record if there is no match.

Take a look at this article for an explanation of the different types of joins:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

UPDATE:

I'm not sure where the first column of your desired results is coming form but the query below should get you the desired results:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.sam_subject, t3.subject
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
on t1.email_id = t2.sam_msg_id
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3
on t1.email_id = t3.id
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Comment: Updated my answer.  This will return `null` when there is no corresponding value.  You can throw a `COALESCE` in there if you'd like to change that to an empty string or something.